# Recipes for most compatible slideshows and/or carousels?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I'm getting ready to implement a carousel for client in Drupal 7. I've been searching for information about how to implement carousels and slideshows for maximum compatibility. I've installed several modules in my search and I realize that there is not an out of the box complete solution.

Most of the modules I've tried will make a mess of the page when js is disabled, some of them are buggy on mobile devices etc. I've seen some CSS3 solutions but haven't tried them yet by reason of not knowing the classes employed by them and the level of support they have in browsers/devices. I'd like to ask the community for what solutions exist aside from not using carousels and slideshows to accomplish this. A reasonably compatible solution that looks and functions ok, even on non js enabled browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common formula I implement can work for just about any JS library.

Assuming you are attaching slides to a content type, here is how I go about it.

First, you will need File Entity, for the ability to add fields to file types.

You can use the default Image type, or, create a special one like 'Slide', if you'd like to isolate field and behavior.

1. Add an image field to a content type. Set the widget to 'Media' embed.
2. Set cardinality
3. Hide field display from all view modes
4. Create a new view mode, called 'Slideshow' or 'Carousel' whatever you desire
5. In the new view mode, set the image reference field to render the image in a view mode from the file entity configuration.
6. In Image (or your new) file type, add some fields like Title, Text, and Link. Configure the chosen file display to set those fields however you like.
7. Create a template representing that file display with the markup you desire and placement of fields.
8. Create a View, add a Block display, and add a contextual filter of node nid, based on url value (when on node pages).
9. Set the view to only output the Rendered Entity: Slideshow mode. No fields.
10. Put the block in your designated slideshow region.

When adding images on the content type(s), you should have a ctools window after uploading that presents the fields you added in step 6 - that is for setting headers, text, and 'read more' link on each image.

This will output the markup you provided in those templates on nodes who have one or more files attached. From here, you would want to tweak markup to match whatever slide JS library you select and some CSS tweaking as well. Then, you can hook up an initializer in a JS file in your theme, to call as you need.

This might take 30-60 minutes to setup, but it has been the most bulletproof way for me to allow someone to add a slideshow or hero (just 1 image) to a content page while being open and flexible to whatever slide/carousel library may be required.

My favorite plugins/libraries for slide functionality are Zurb Orbit and slick.js. I don't usually need or implement any modules to do these anymore, for the smallest possible implementation without a ton of overhead.

That said, if you are perhaps using a Foundation based theme, you might find it worthwhile to leverage [Field Orbit](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_orbit). It is built a little like the steps above, but uses a field formatter to simplify the implementation part. Disclaimer, I built that many moons ago - but I have not made any changes to it lately. I believe it works with Foundation 5.x as well.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I will give this a try over the weekend and post with my results.

Comment: Most would likely say "Use Views Slideshow!" but I've never really liked it.

Comment: working through your example, how can you prevent displaying all of a content type if js is disabled? It looks like the slideshow libraries have settings to do this which conflict with setting pagers on the view itself.

Comment: Why do you need a pager on the view? The Views only job is to spit out the node in a view mode in this example. I don't use pagers.

Comment: I set cardibality on the image field to prevent more than 6 slides let's say - then mark it up in the templates. I use the same logic to construct the slider navigation if the library provides one.

Comment: Ah I see, you did say set cardinality but I didn't realize the effect it had on this setup or what to set it to. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Yeah the goal is to render out the markup the library is expecting, without worrying about implementing the library until you have it output on the page. Hence my affinity for view modes, templates, and Views.

Comment: Ok, I see how this works now. I'll use it for the site's front page, but I also  use the social content module to auto generate content from instagram. I'm not sure how I could apply content from feeds using this approach. Would it be possible to adapt your answer to include existing content or is this the subject for a different question? Either way I'm marking this as the answer to my original question.

Comment: Not sure... I only do uploads to the page most of the time.